# A natural syntax for a Query that holds

Tags: syntax, associations, hold, language-design

Often I have an unevaluated expression in a `RuleDelayed` `Key`-`Value` pair and subsequently want to access the value unevaluated. For example, say I want to `Query` `assoc` to yield `HoldForm[Range[0,10]]`

```
assoc = <|"a" ->  <|"b" :> Range[0, 10]|>|>;
```

This can be done readily enough (e.g. start with `Query["a",{"b"}]@assoc`, `KeyValuePattern`etc.) but it seems like there should be a more natural syntax?

Comment: `Query["a", HoldForm[#"b"] &]@assoc`

Comment: @Edmund Yep, that's natural enough - thanks - quick accept if posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `HoldForm`.

```
Query["a", HoldForm[#"b"] &]@assoc
(* HoldForm[Range[0,10]] *)
```

Hope this helps.